# Why ComboBox does not set and get ItemData in a loop?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, winapi, combobox

I want to save a 'username' and 'ID' in a ComboBox in visual Studio 2010 and WIN32 (c++). Following code is for setting itemdata to combobox:

```
HWND hCB;
hCB = CreateWindowEx(0, L"COMBOBOX", 0x00, 
        CBS_DROPDOWNLIST | CBS_HASSTRINGS | CBS_NOINTEGRALHEIGHT | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_VSCROLL,
        10, 10, 200, 100, 
        hWnd, NULL, (HINSTANCE) GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_HINSTANCE), NULL);

WCHAR sTemp[256];
for (int i =0 ; i<4 ; i++)
{
    wsprintf(sTemp, L"%s%d", L"User", i);
    SendMessage(hCB, CB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM) sTemp);
    wsprintf(sTemp, L"%s%d", L"ID", i);
    SendMessage(hCB, CB_SETITEMDATA, (WPARAM)i, (LPARAM)sTemp);
}
```

And code for getting itemdata from combobox is:

```
WCHAR *sTemp;
for (int i=0; i < 4 ; i++)
{
    sTemp = (WCHAR *)SendMessage(hCB, CB_GETITEMDATA, (WPARAM)i, 0);
    MessageBox(NULL, sTemp, NULL, MB_OK);
}
```

> > The problem is, MessageBox does not show anything. 
> >        When I checked the first part of code by adding a CB_GETITEMDATA message for each combobox item, and a MessageBox to show result, I've found that all values of items' itemdata is "ID3", that is the last itemdata in the list.
> >        I think the codes are straightforward, But I can't find what wrong is with my code?

Answer (score 2):

You set the items' data to a pointer to the sTemp temporary string (the same for all items by the way).

When that variable goes out of scope, the pointer becomes invalid, and de-referencing it may cause a crash.

P.S. Just noticed your last comment. If you do it in the same scope, the sTemp contains the last text you wsprintf'ed to it, and every item points to it.

[added]

If you want to add string data to each item in your ComboBox, you need to allocate those strings. For example:

```
char* p = new char[some_buffer_length];
```

Then use that p in your call to set item data.

Don't forget to free the memory when you are done by calling:

```
delete [] p;
```

for each of your items.

Comment: So how to assign a string to an item itemdata in a loop? Till now I thought combobox uses internal data structure to save itemdata!

Comment: What a mess! If I should allocate memory for each itemdata, so I make a data structure or file to save data. All the way, thanks to your attention.

Comment: You are welcome. But this is NOT a mess at all! Someone (you?) should own the data pointed to by ComboBox's item data. Typically, you would have some data structure to hold relevant data (a vector, a map, etc.) and point to some of its element. Alternatively, you could point to some static text; then you are not responsible for clean-up.

Comment: Sometimes ago, I had used an ownerdraw ListBox to assign a HBITMAP file as an itemdata for every item, and it worked! So I thought it is poosible to do so for ComboBox and strings.

Comment: You must have allocated memory for those HBITMAP somewhere, and if you didn't clean up after yourself - you had a leak...  Anyway, I think I have answered your "Why..." question :)

Comment: @Shaheen Each item data is simply a pointer, which has to point somewhere.